# jSONArray.toJSONString() is giving not a valid string

Tags: java, json, rest, parsing, json-simple

I want to write the rest response of my endpoint that is a json in a file from controller i'm returning JSONArray OBJ in response

```
  [
            {
                "_fields": {
                  "key1":"value1",
                    "key2","value2"
                }
            },
            {
                "_fields": {
                    "key1":"value1",
                    "key2","value2"
                }
            },
            {
                "_count": 12,
                "links": [
                    {
                        "rel": "prev",
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/someprevurl"

                    },
                    {
                        "rel": "next",
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/somenexturl"


                    },
                    {
                        "rel": "self",
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/selfurl"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
```

I've override the to string methods this is my method where i'm trying to write the jsonarray into the file

```
public static void generateFile(JSONArray fileContent, String directory, String fileName, String extension) {
    logger.info("Writing into the file : {}{} start time : {}", fileName, extension, Instant.now());
    try {
        FileWriter file = new FileWriter(directory + fileName + extension);

        file.write(fileContent.toJSONString());
        file.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("Exception generated while generating file : {}", e.getMessage());

    }
}
```

but after using toJSONString the response in file is like this

```
[
        {
            "_fields": MyDTONAME [
              key1=value1,
                key2="value2"
            ]
        },
        {
             "_fields": MyDTONAME [
              key1=value1,
                key2="value2"
            ]
        },
        [
            "_count": 12,
    links: [.......]
        ]
    ]
```

do i need to define the complete format like replacing `[]` to `{}` & `=` to `:`.jsonstring is not suppose to do that  "" also missing so what to i do ? Please suggest

Comment: *"I've override the to string methods"* Why? Why not let Gson do its job of rendering the correct JSON?

Comment: I am however very confused how your code compiles, given that Gson's class is named `JsonArray`, and you seem to be using a class named `JSONArray`.

Comment: You need to fix json error first, you can use JSON Formatter & Validator Tool like: https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: @Andreas M using org.json.simple.JSONArray

Comment: @Andreas 
iusing {${member.name()}":"${member.value}", "${otherMembers}"}    template format i format my tostring seems working what is a better approach

Comment: @Himanshi *"M using **org.json.simple**.JSONArray"* Then **why** did you tag [tag:gson] instead of [tag:json-simple]?

Comment: @Himanshi *"what is a better approach"* Not to re-invent the wheel, i.e. don't try to generate correct JSON, when there are so very many nice and free libraries already able to do it for you, which have been tested so they do it right.

Comment: @Andreas thanks i'm trying with your suggested way

Answer (score 0):

Don't know what you've messed up, since you didn't share the relevant code, but you tagged [gson](/questions/tagged/gson), so here is how you could generate that JSON output using Gson, and simply defining the data in Maps and Lists.

The code uses Java 9's `List.of()` and `Map.of()` to simplify the data building.

```
List<?> fileContent = List.of(
        Map.of("_fields", Map.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2")),
        Map.of("_fields", Map.of("key1", "value1", "key2", "value2")),
        Map.of("_count", 12, "links", List.of(
                Map.of("rel", "prev", "href", "http://localhost:8080/someprevurl"),
                Map.of("rel", "next", "href", "http://localhost:8080/somenexturl"),
                Map.of("rel", "self", "href", "http://localhost:8080/selfurl")
        ))
);

Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
String json = gson.toJson(fileContent);
System.out.println(json);
```

*Output*

```json
[
  {
    "_fields": {
      "key2": "value2",
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_fields": {
      "key2": "value2",
      "key1": "value1"
    }
  },
  {
    "_count": 12,
    "links": [
      {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/someprevurl",
        "rel": "prev"
      },
      {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/somenexturl",
        "rel": "next"
      },
      {
        "href": "http://localhost:8080/selfurl",
        "rel": "self"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: @andres I've JSONArray and not list

Comment: @Himanshi This answer is based of the *fact* that you said you're using Gson, and is simply illustrating that you should be doing any "toString" implementations to get the output you need. Whether the input is an array, a `List`, a `JSONArray`, or some other collection that Gson understands, is entirely beside the point.